# Installing node.js and mongodb in a production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache, server

My company has it's own Apache Tomcat server, running MySQL and PHP websites on it.

Can I install Node.js and MongoDB in there without affecting other projects?

Comment: This is a question only you can answer. These service should have no issues running on the same host, but you should consider the impact you may cause on other app when you start stealing CPU cycles, or system resources.

Comment: Matt, the usage of resources gets affected with every new project, regardless the technology, isn't it?
My question here is more simple, if both languages (PHP and Node.js) can coexist in the same server.

Comment: Why do you think they would not be physically able to?

Comment: That is my question, you can simply answer yes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install . But before doing that you have to take care of this thing.

1. How much physical memory you have ?
2. How much amount of RAM is average free for use ?
3. How much CPU core you have free to use ?
4. How much CPU utilization currently happening?

Then you can look to node.js howmuch CPU core you need for node.js .

If you have simple app then 1 core . And check same for mongodb . How much data you need to same .

No one can tell without knowing this parameter . You have to look on this parameter and judge if you are good to go .

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend that your company, starts using virtualization technology. e.g Hyper-V or VMware-esxi. Then you can have your primary production server running with all of your client's websites and/or applications on one Virtual Machine/Appliance. Then make a copy of that server on to a secondary VM. Now you can safely test new software and/or projects. Inclusively with VMs you can enable full system backups easily making any major system failure easily recoverable.